# Swift structs: no type named 'Business' in module

Tags: xcode, struct, swift3, ios-frameworks, siesta-swift

I'm building a project using Swift 3 and Xcode 8.1. First I created an API client using Siesta on a framework and I'm including it on my mail project, but when I try to use an struct from the framework to do a downcast I get an error `No type named 'Business' in module 'ApiClient'`, I've tried using it like `ApiClient.Business` but no success...

My framework is in a workspace together with another dependencies injected by carthage, and I can call another instances from it (like the API itself) but I need to access this to be able to downcast the results. I've also tried adding the framework under **Link Binary With Libraries**, **Compile Sources**, **Embed Frameworks**, **Embedded Binaries** and **Linked Frameworks and Libraries**, but can't make it work...

Here's my code

```
//
//  BusinessesViewController.swift
//

import UIKit
import ApiClient
import Siesta

class BusinessesViewController: UIViewController, ResourceObserver{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        globalInstance.MyAPI.businesses.addObserver(self).loadIfNeeded()
    }

    func resourceChanged(_ resource: Resource, event: ResourceEvent) {

        let businesses: Array = resource.typedContent(ifNone: [])
        if(businesses.count > 0){
            let object : ApiClient.Business =  businesses[0] as! ApiClient.Business // <-- error here
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}



//
//  global.swift
//

import Foundation
import ApiClient

class Global {
    var MyAPI :ApiClientService 

    init() {
        MyAPI = ApiClientService(baseURL: "http://test.myproject.com")
    }

}
var globalInstance = Global()



//
//  Business.swift  -- from ApiClient framework
//

import SwiftyJSON
import Foundation
struct Business {
    let name, id: String?
    let userId: Int?
    let description: String?

    init(json: JSON) throws {
        id          = json["id"].string
        userId     =  json["user_id"].int
        name        = json["name"].string
        description = json["description"].string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a noob error, just needed to add `public` to the struct :)

Comment: Im having a similar problem. My protocol is written is swift and isnt added automatically to my framework.h header file, so i added the .swift file to public headers, but it still isnt being found. (the error I get is "No type named "protocolname" in module "frameworkName".) Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I've also added public to the protocol...

Comment: @Jeremie, without having more context and code hard to tell. Maybe worth checking if you have `import Foundation` and also link it to your framework target.